# Performance Counters and IMC Counter Not Matching

Tags: linux-kernel, performancecounter, perf, memory-access, intel-pmu

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz` (`Haswell`) processor. In a relatively **idle** situation, I ran the following `Perf` commands and their outputs are shown, **below**. The counters are `offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.any_response` and `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss`:

```
sudo perf stat -a -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.any_response,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss sleep 10

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

     3,713,037      offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.any_response                                   

     2,909,573      mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss


  10.016644133 seconds time elapsed
```

These two values seem **consistent**, as the latter **excludes** *prefetch* requests and those **not** targeted at `DRAM`. But they do **not** match the read counter in the `IMC`. This counter is called `UNC_IMC_DRAM_DATA_READS` and documented [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/monitoring-integrated-memory-controller-requests-in-the-2nd-3rd-and-4th-generation-intel.html). I **read** the counter **reread** it `1` second later. The difference was around `30,000,000` **(EDITED)**. If **multiplied** by `10` (to estimate for `10` seconds) the resulting value will be around `300` million **(EDITED)**, which is `100` **times** the value of the **above-mentioned** performance counters **(EDITED)**. It is **nowhere** near `3` million! What am I **missing**?

---

P.S.: The difference is **much** smaller (but **still** large), when the system has **more** load.

The question is also asked, here:
https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Tuning-Performance/Performance-Counters-and-IMC-Counter-Not-Matching/m-p/1288832

---

**UPDATE:**

Please note that [`PCM`](https://github.com/opcm/pcm) output matches my `IMC` counter reads.

This is the relevant [`PCM`](https://github.com/opcm/pcm) output:
[image]
The values for columns `READ`, `WRITE` and `IO` are **calculated** based on `UNC_IMC_DRAM_DATA_READS`, `UNC_IMC_DRAM_DATA_WRITES` and `UNC_IMC_DRAM_IO_REQUESTS`, respectively. It seems that requests **classified** as `IO` will **be** either `READ` or `WRITE`. In other words, during the **depicted** one second interval, **almost** (because of the **inaccuracy** reported [in the above-mentioned doc](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/monitoring-integrated-memory-controller-requests-in-the-2nd-3rd-and-4th-generation-intel.html)) `2.01`GB **of** the `2.42`GB `READ` and `WRITE` requests **belong** to `IO`. Based on **this** explanation, the above **three** columns seem **consistent** with each other.

The problem is that there still exists a **LARGE** gap between the `IMC` and `PMC` values!

The situation is the **same** when I boot in **runlevel** `1`. The **processes** on the scheduler are **one of** `swapper`, `kworker` and `migration`. **Disk IO** is almost `85`KB/s. I'm wondering **what** leads to such a (relatively) **huge** amount of `IO`. Is it possible to **detect** that (e.g., using a `counter` or a *tool*)?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I think that there is something **wrong** with the `IO` column. It is **always** something in the range `[1.99,2.01]`, **regardless** of the amount of load in the system!

---

**UPDATE 3:**

In *runlevel `1`*, the **average** number of occurrences of the `uops_retired.all` event in a **1-second interval** is `15,000,000`. During the **same** period, the number of **read** requests recorded by the associated `IMC` counter is around `30,000,000`. In other words, *assuming* that **all** memory accesses are directly **caused** by cpu instructions, for **each** retired micro-operation, there exists **two** memory accesses. This seems **impossible** specially concerning the fact that there exist **multiple** levels of caches. Therefore, in the **idle scenario**, perhaps, the *read* accesses are **caused** by `IO`.

Comment: Why are you showing two different runs of `perf` (from different time intervals), instead of just using two events for the same run like `-e foo,bar` or `-e foo -e bar`?.  Presumably one 10-second interval is similar to another, but there's no need to assume that, and it would make your question more compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it was mostly caused by the **GPU device**. This was the reason for exclusion from performance counters. Here is the relevant output for a sample execution of `PCM` on a *relatively idle* system with *resolution* `3840x2160` and *refresh rate* `60` using [xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/a/155351/926952):
[image: Relevant PCM Output for High-Resolution Case]
And this is for the situation with *resolution* `800x600` and the same *refresh rate* (i.e., `60`):
[image: Relevant PCM Output for Low-Resolution Case]
As can be seen, changing screen resolution reduced **read** and **IO** **traffic** considerably (more than `100x`!).

Comment: The iGPU might be taking advantage of L3 cache.  Anyway, interesting; putting the screen to sleep might reduce competition even more.  (e.g. `sleep 0.4; xset dpms force off` to give you a chance to release enter before xset runs, the let `intel_gpu_top -l` produce some lines while the monitors is off)